# An unfair coin is thrown until heads appears for the first time, but a maximum of $n$ times.

Tags: probability

what is the probability to stop at time $k\in\{1, ..., n\}$?

my thoughts so far:
$\Omega :=\{H,N\}^n$, where $H$ is head and $n$ is a number.
$\Pr(\{k\})=(1-p)p^{k-1}$ geometric distribution

i dont know how to continue because i don't have a probability for head or number. ?

Comment: If $p = $ chance of heads, and $q = 1-p$, then chance of 3 tails on the 1st 3 coin tosses, and then 1 head on the 4th coin toss is $q^3 \times p.$

Comment: I would assume the answer should be given in terms of the variables $p$ and $n$.

Comment: You are correct. For less than $n$ this is a geometric distribution. The probability to stop at the $n$th throw is the probability of not getting heads for the $n-1$ previous one.

Comment: Simplest approach, given fixed $n$, is to provide a formula applicable to all $k \in \{1,2,\cdots, (n-1)\}.$  Then chance of stopping on the $n$-th toss would $1 - $ chance of not stopping at any time before $n$-th toss.

Comment: and do i have to write: k=1-> P(1)=(1-p)p^0=1-p, k=2->P(2)=(1-p)p^1=p-p^2, k=3->P(3)=(1-p)p^3=p^2-p^3....k=(n-1)=P(n-1)=(1-p)p^(n-2), k=n->P(n)=(1-p)p^n-1    ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call the probability that the coin comes up head $p$ (and so tail comes up with $1-p$ probability). Then the probability that we stop at exactly time $1 \le k < n$ is found: we need $k-1$ many tails followed by a head at try $k$ (so that we stop) so by independence of trials (letting $S$ denote the "stopping time")

$$P(S=k)=p(1-p)^{k-1} \text{ when } 1 \le k < n$$

The probability that we stop at exactly $n$ (the maximal number of tries) is that we have $n-1$ tails for the first $n-1$ trials. The final toss doesn't affect the stopping time any more so

$$P(S=n) = (1-p)^{n-1}$$

And $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is the complete set of values for $S$, so we're done.
As a check, verify that these indeed sum exactly to $1$:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} p(1-p)^{k-1} = p\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(1-p)^k = p \frac{1-(1-p)^{(n-2) + 1}}{1-(1-p)} = 1 - (1-p)^{n-1}$$

so adding $P(S=n)$ yields $1$.

Comment: im sorry i dont get the last step. why is 1-(1-p)^n-1 =1?

Comment: @kellyneedshelp Read better:  $1-(1-p)^{n-1} + (1-p)^{n-1} =1 $ is what I actually said..

Comment: ok understood! so you say probability 1 for trials between 1 and n-1 and probability 2 for n trials and at least you add both probabilities  (1+2) to show that youre right

Comment: @kellyneedshelp Yes, as an extra verification. The sum of $P(S=k)$ over all possible $k$ should be $1$.

Comment: ok one last question: why isnt there a p by P(S=n)=(1-p)^n-1, why not P(S=n)=p(1-p)^n-1?

Comment: @kellyneedshelp that would imply the last toss has to be head. But we also stop if the last toss is also tails. So no extra $p$.

Comment: hm i dont get it... can you explain it in an other way?

Comment: @kellyneedshelp No. Reread the comments and the post: stopping at $n$ is exactly the same $n-1$ tails on the first tries. Because the max number of tries is given to be $n$.

Comment: ok now i think i got it

Comment: can you explain me the step from sum to fraction

Comment: @kellyneedshelp standard geometric sum formula: $\sum_{i=0}^{i=m} x^i = \frac{1-x^{m+1}}{1-x}$